# Writing characters using binary values?

Tags: c#, variables, binary

How would I convert binary values that I choose, into their corresponding UTF-16 character value? I need to put this into a variable, not a file.

Comment: If 01 is A, why is 11 (decimal 3) B?

Comment: i was using 00:a,01:A,10:b,11:B i don't know why it just seamed more standard :P

Comment: You do realize that several text encodings [already exist](http://xkcd.com/927/), right? Why not use ASCII or UTF-8?

Comment: i should have clarified, i was giving that as an example. I am indeed trying to convert it into UTF-16 i'll edit the question...

Comment: If it's an arbitrary binary value that you choose, you'll need to do your own mapping from those values to some existing encoding, then convert those bytes into UTF-16. Basically, what you're describing *is* creating a new encoding.

Comment: Sorry, I rewrote it, its much less confusing now

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496). What may be confusing you is that [Stack Overflow is not like all those other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/172496)

Comment: Let me see if I can explain this: You have arbitrary binary values, also known as "numbers". Each one corresponds to a character. This is called a character encoding. You then want to take your numbers and translate them into a different encoding (UTF-16). Why not use an existing encoding?

Comment: what I was trying to do is loop through each character that exists in whatever encoding, starting at the whatever is assigned for 00000000 and just loop through writing out each value, but now that I think about it, I dont need to use binary for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could take advantage of the fact that several encodings already exist:

```
using System.Text;

var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 65, 66, 67 });    // "ABC"
var chr = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[] { 65 })[0];          // 'A'
```